# HTML/CSS page width unexpected results

Tags: html, css

I have the following:
jsfiddle.net/ed47D/

```
<nav>
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="navLeft">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="navOption" id="navHome">Home</td>
                    <td class="navOption" id="navProducts">Products</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="navCenter">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navRight">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="navOption" id="navServices">Services</td>
                    <td class="navOption" id="navContact">Contact Us</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
nav{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
}
.navWrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.navLeft{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
.navLeft table{
    width:100%;
}
.navLeft table td{
    width:50%;
}
.navCenter{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:300px;;
}
.navRight{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.navRight table{
    width:100%;
}
.navRight table td{
    width:50%;
}
```

I need the navigation bar itself to span 100%, But a smaller element (navWrapper) to span 900px and be centered, However when the page is created and scrolled the navigation bar does not span 100%.

Comment: Beside your actual question, your HTML markup seems semantically wrong (a nav bar is no tabular data!) and also looks like "Divitis". Additionally today there are lots of viewports smaller than 900px. I strongly recommend to rethink your whole approach!

Comment: I dont understand? Nav bars cant store information? @Netsurfer could you possibly contact me via skype? :sleawnis2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS thusly:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed47D/1/)

```
nav {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center; /* centre child content */
    background-color:black;
}
.navWrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* concatenated margin setting */
    overflow:hidden; /* contain child floats to give element height */
}
```